# PHP include in Joomla! 1.7

Tags: php, joomla1.7

I need to include a file in one of my components in Joomla!. The file I want to include is located in the root of my Joomla! directory (where my index.php file is but my the file where the include is going is deeper in the administrator folder. It is in this file:

administrator/components/com_rsform/helpers/rsform.php

How can i put an include in that file that will link back to the file in my root of Joomla!? I need the path to be relative so that it is environment independent. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php include_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .DS. 'components'.DS.'com_rsform'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'rsform.php'); ?>
```

There are also other variables that may help you:

JPATH_SITE = /your_local_path_to_site/ i.e: /var/www/mysite

JPATH_COMPONENT = /your_local_path_to_site/components/the_component_you_are_in i.e: /var/www/mysite/componentes/com_rsform

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need it the other way around. It has to be from my component to the other file.

Comment: you can use the following to access any file in your root:

<?php include_once (JPATH_SITE .DS.'yourfile.php'); ?>

Comment: No, you dont have to declare that variable because it is already declared by the application.
JPATH_SITE is meant to represent the root path of the JSite application, just as JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR is meant to represent the root path of the JAdministrator application.

Comment: JPATH_BASE is the root path for the current requested application.... so if you are in the administrator application, JPATH_BASE == JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR... if you are in the site application JPATH_BASE == JPATH_SITE... if you are in the installation application JPATH_BASE == JPATH_INSTALLATION.

JPATH_ROOT is the root path for the Joomla install and does not depend upon any application

Comment: So I should be using JPATH_ROOT to get from inside administrator to the site application?

Comment: I am in this file:

joomla/administrator/components/com_rsform/helpers/rsform.php 

and I wanna include this file:

joomla/rtds_runtime_env.php

Comment: You can use either JPATH_ROOT or JPATH_SITE. To make it easier you can dump the value of the variable by: `<?php die(var_dump(JPATH_SITE)); ?>` helping you to determine wether is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

**JPATH_SITE** is constant always contains a path on the server's file system.

Please have a look onto this one.

http://www.latenight-coding.com/joomla-faqs/developers/get-path-joomla-folder.html